# Using JavaScript to fill out hidden input before php submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a submit button on a form that says this:

```
<input type="submit" name="add_submit" onclick="return getCoord()" value="Add Location" />
```

Two hidden input fields like this:

```
<input id="long" name="long" type="hidden"  value=""  />
<input id="lat" name="lat" type="hidden"  value="" />
```

The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCoord() {

        address = document.getElementById('street').value + " " + document.getElementById('city').value + " " + document.getElementById('state').value + " " + document.getElementById('zip').value;
        console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
                document.getElementById('long').value = longitude;


            } 
        });

    } 
</script>
```

on the `php` post:

```
        $new_long = $database -> escape_value($_POST['long']);
        $new_lat = $database -> escape_value($_POST['lat']);
```

I want the JS function to fill out the value of the `long` and `lat` fields BEFORE the form submits; then on the `php` post I want to grab the input field -- but it returns blank.  Is there a typo a problem with logic?

Note:  I confirmed the address is being logged in the JS console correctly.

EDIT:  I am actually getting a DB query fail error but it SEEMS the result of that is blank  `long` `lat` entries. These coordinates are being put into a DB.

Comment: @woofmeow  I removed it and same result.

Comment: Try getting the co-ordinates server side(with a server-side api), or prevent the user from submitting the form until geocode completes.

Comment: @Musa  Maybe just an auto JavaScript watcher function that gets coordinates when ALL appropriate fields are filled out?  (form can not be submitted until address is complete)

Comment: btw as mentioned onclick won't be invoked always use onsubmit

Comment: @woofmeow isnt the value being set here?  `document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;                 document.getElementById('long').value = longitude;`

Comment: Sorry I must have been blind to not see it. Perhaps what you will need to do is reconsider the timing of calling your functions since the value is not being returned in time (cause its ajax) by the geocoder api for it to be changes. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google API maps is async, so before it has finished you have submited form. Do it on server or try with Observer.

**edit**

```js
var geoCompleted = false;

function getCoord() {

    address = document.getElementById('street').value + " " + document.getElementById('city').value + " " + document.getElementById('state').value + " " + document.getElementById('zip').value;
    console.log(address);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
            document.getElementById('long').value = longitude;
            geoCompleted = true
            $('#form-id').submit();

        } 
    });
   return geoCompleted
}
```